# json_encode adding a null:null entry

Tags: php, json

I have this code - it's not done by me :s and don't have time to replace the deprecated calls.

```
<?php

$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$db=mysql_connect('localhost','carros_mil1','K-Jw)ureB.}M');
mysql_select_db('carros_mil0',$db);
$nombreListModelo = 'modelo_'.str_replace(" ","_",strtolower($_REQUEST['nombreMarca']));

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT (identificador) AS id
   FROM modelos
   WHERE nombre = '".$nombreListModelo."'";
$rs=mysql_query($sql);
$i=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $vectorModelo[$i] = $row['id'];
    $i++;
}

$sql = "SELECT attribute_id
    FROM eav_attribute
    WHERE attribute_code = '".$nombreListModelo."'";
$rs  = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
$id1 = $row['attribute_id'];

$sql= "SELECT eao.option_id AS option_id
    FROM eav_attribute_option eao, eav_attribute_option_value eaov
    WHERE eao.option_id=eaov.option_id AND attribute_id = ".$id1." ORDER BY eaov.value";
$rs=mysql_query($sql);

$retorno = array();
$bandera = true;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

    $bandera = false;
    $sql2= "SELECT value, option_id
        FROM eav_attribute_option_value
        WHERE option_id = ".$row['option_id']."
        ORDER BY value";
    $rs2=mysql_query($sql2);
    $row2= mysql_fetch_array($rs2);

    if ($_REQUEST['bandera']=='vende') {
        if (!is_null($row2['value'])) $retorno[$row2['value']] = $row2['value'];
    } else {
        $existe=false;
        for($k=0;$k<count($vectorModelo);$k++) {
            if($row2['option_id'] == $vectorModelo[$k]) {
                $existe=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if($existe) {
            if($_REQUEST['tipo']=='contactenos')
                if (!is_null($row2['value'])) $retorno[$row2['value']] = $row2['value'];
            else
                if (!is_null($row2['option_id'])) $retorno[$row2['option_id']] = $row2['value'];
        }
    }
}

if($bandera)
    $retorno[''] = 'Todos';

header('Content-Type: application/json');
//echo json_encode($retorno);
foreach($retorno as $k => $v) {
    printf("%s => %s\n", $k, $v);
}
print_r($retorno);
echo json_encode($retorno);
```

Since I noticed something strange in the generated json, I added 2 different ways of printing the contents of the array.

The JSON way adds me a null:null entry. The strange case is that I'm checking `!is_null($row2['value'])` each time I add an element.

When I hit the url under certain parameters, I get:

```
Elantra => Elantra
Getz => Getz
H1 => H1
i-10 => i-10
New Accent => New Accent
Santa Fé => Santa Fé
Tucson => Tucson
Array
(
    [Elantra] => Elantra
    [Getz] => Getz
    [H1] => H1
    [i-10] => i-10
    [New Accent] => New Accent
    [Santa Fé] => Santa Fé
    [Tucson] => Tucson
)
{"Elantra":"Elantra","Getz":"Getz","H1":"H1","i-10":"i-10","New Accent":"New Accent",null:null,"Tucson":"Tucson"}
```

The first 6 lines correspond to a custom print `foreach` loop. There's also a `print_r` call which only shows 6 elements. The 3rd form - which is the actual one I need - shows a null value.

So: Why is `$retorno` accepting null entries when I check the null condition beforehand? **considering** this script is full - no missing code here.

Comment: Could you investigate reducing this script somewhat - it'd be much easier to answer if you removed code not relevant to the problem.

Comment: show the script that has the specified output.

Comment: THIS is the script. THIS is the full script. And the biggest part is the relevant one - the loop.

Comment: Santa Fe is your answer. There's something to do with UTF encoding. I ran into this the other week.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21688653/json-encode-and-getting-null-values-issue-with-utf-8

Comment: Dude! :D You (@Hammerstein) deserve a raise in your monthly check. Unfortunately I'm not your boss :p. Put it as an answer.

Comment: Your answer makes far more sense

Comment: Actually is based on what you said. I only added the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Thanks @Hammerstein - don't know why you didn't write that as an answer).

The problem is that one of such values was not correctly being encoded, since it was not an ANSI value and was not encoded in UTF8. In this way, since "Santa Fé" had a "strange" character, it was encoded as null instead of "Santa F\u00e9".

Tip: **Never** assume your database is using an *utf8_* charset

The solution was to explicitly encode the values when composing the array:

```
...

$bandera = false;
$sql2= "SELECT value, option_id
    FROM eav_attribute_option_value
    WHERE option_id = ".$row['option_id']."
    ORDER BY value";
$rs2=mysql_query($sql2);
$row2= mysql_fetch_array($rs2);

//ENCODE the values to a good charset
$value = utf8_encode($row2['value']);
$option_id = utf8_encode($row['option_id'])

if ($_REQUEST['bandera']=='vende') {
    $retorno[$value] = $value;
} else {
    $existe=false;
    for($k=0;$k<count($vectorModelo);$k++) {
        if($row2['option_id'] == $vectorModelo[$k]) {
            $existe=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($existe) {
        if($_REQUEST['tipo']=='contactenos')
            $retorno[$value] = $value;
        else
            $retorno[$option_id] = $value;
    }
}

...
```